# Vim not using 256 color, ncurses-term installed, "xterm-256color: command not found"

Tags: 16.04, vim, colors, ubuntu-mate

First I want to say I am using Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

I'm trying to get the solarized colorscheme to work in vim but am running into problems. It works fine in gvim, but I seem to only be getting 8 color support in vim.

It is also not specific to the solarized colorscheme, many other colorschemes do not appear correctly.

I have installed the `ncurses-term` package, and set `TERM=xterm-256color` in a variety of different ways (manually, in .bashrc, or as a command when mate-terminal is run).

When I run `tput colors`  I get `256`

I also have, or have tried the following in different combinations in my `.vimrc`

```
 syntax on
 set t_Co=256
 let g:solarized_termcolors=256
 set background=dark
```

BUT when I run `$TERM` it gives me `xterm-256color: command not found`. I think this is where the issue is.

I also know that `/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color` exists, but `/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color` does not exist. Therefore I have tried copying `xterm-256color` into `/usr/share/terminfo/x/` but that didn't help either.

Comment: Not the main issue here, but you get `command not found` error, because bash replaces `$TERM` with `xterm-256color` and then tries to execute is as a command. Try `echo $TERM` and you should get no errors.

Comment: I'm not a Vim specialist, but are you sure that the color scheme is actually getting enabled? What about `colorscheme solarized`?

Comment: Yes it is being enabled, I can change colorschemes, and change the filenames of the colorscheme to make sure I am actually enabling the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't take a close enough look at the 256-color palette, the colors I was looking for are not in the palette, and thus that is the reason I was having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the Preferences in the menu of the terminal and change the Profile colour scheme to reflect you want solarized.